# In Windows 7 X64, statusBar does not show text for the panels starting from the 11th correctly

Tags: delphi, windows-7, statusbar, common-controls

**Summarization:**
(1) This is very likely to be a bug.  However, I cannot say for sure whether it is more related to 64bit OS, or VCL, or MFC wrapper. Please check the answers and comments below from Delphi experts.
(2) Workaround for me:
a. The situation is that I have `six` key-value `pairs` to show in the status bar. The values will be changed in run time.
b. It seems I cannot `set text` for more than `10` panels.
c. In this respect,  I will use `six` calls of `set text` for the values, and use `two` calls for `set text` for the last two keys. Thus, I don't have to exceed the `10` limit.
d. In order to make `set text` work, I need provide different text that it already has.
e. Sample code can thus be described as:

```
// Designtime
stat1.Panels[0].Text := 'Key1'
stat1.Panels[2].Text := 'Key2'
stat1.Panels[4].Text := 'Key3'
stat1.Panels[6].Text := 'Key4'
stat1.Panels[8].Text := 'Key5__'
stat1.Panels[10].Text := 'Key6__'


// runtime
stat1.Panels[1].Text := 'Value1'
stat1.Panels[3].Text := 'Value2'
stat1.Panels[5].Text := 'Value3'
stat1.Panels[6].Text := 'Value4'
stat1.Panels[9].Text := 'Value5'
stat1.Panels[11].Text := 'Value6'    

stat1.Panels[8].Text := 'Key5'
stat1.Panels[10].Text := 'Key6'
```

==================================================================

In my Windows 7 X64, the statusBar does not show text for the panels starting from the 11th correctly.

(1)
New an empty VCL application project `without` saving it, if I set the Text for the 11th status panel at design time, the text will not be shown at all at run time. (See the attached pictures.)

(2) 
If I save it and reopen it, the text will also not be shown in design time.

(3) 
If I set the Text at run time, the text will be shown only when the new text is different from the old one. Say the Text for the 11th panel is set to `'try'` at design time:

```
Self.stat1.Panels[10].Text := 'try';         // 'try' is not shown   
self.stat1.Panels[10].Text := 'try_';        // 'try_' is shown
```

(4)
This behavior only happens on my Windows 7 X64, but not on my Windows XP.

(5)
I would think the same behavior allpies to all Delphi versions.

(6) 
It seems the behavior is more related to Windows version than to Delphi. I mean, the same sample application will shown the above behavior on Windows 7 but not on Windows XP.

(7) 
A sample dfm file is dumped as below:

```
    object Form3: TForm3
      Left = 0
      Top = 0
      Caption = 'Form3'
      ClientHeight = 202
      ClientWidth = 731
      Color = clBtnFace
      Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
      Font.Color = clWindowText
      Font.Height = -11
      Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
      Font.Style = []
      OldCreateOrder = False
      PixelsPerInch = 96
      TextHeight = 13
      object stat1: TStatusBar
        Left = 0
        Top = 183
        Width = 731
        Height = 19
        Panels = <
          item
            Text = '0'
            Width = 50
          end
          item
            Text = '1'
            Width = 50
          end
          item
            Text = '2'
            Width = 50
          end
          item
            Text = '3'
            Width = 50
          end
          item
            Text = '4'
            Width = 50
          end
          item
            Text = '5'
            Width = 50
          end
          item
            Text = '6'
            Width = 50
          end
          item
            Text = '7'
            Width = 50
          end
          item
            Text = '8'
            Width = 50
          end
          item
            Text = '9'
            Width = 50
          end
          item
            Text = '10'
            Width = 50
          end
          item
            Text = '11'
            Width = 50
          end>
        ExplicitLeft = 248
        ExplicitTop = 152
        ExplicitWidth = 0
      end
      object btn1: TButton
        Left = 152
        Top = 40
        Width = 433
        Height = 89
        Caption = 'btn1'
        TabOrder = 1
        OnClick = btn1Click
      end
    end
```

(8) 
Sample pictures:
[image: Designtime]
[image: rumtime]

Could some one help to comment on the possible reason?  Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: @Warren: Thanks very much for your time! I have edited my question to be more clear. Could you have a look?

Comment: Do you have Service Pack 1 installed?

Comment: @Warren: I didn't install SP1 yet.

Comment: @Xichen Li which Delphi version?

Comment: @Jeroen: As Warren and David tried, I would think it applies to all versions.

Comment: I'm running Win7 x64 SP1 FWIW

Comment: Why on earth do you want that many panels in your status bar?

Comment: @Xichen it might be that this is fixed or introduced in some Delphi / Windows combination.

Comment: I tried to reproduce using MFC's wrapper in Visual C++, but my MFC-fu was too weak.

Comment: This problem doesn't show itself when you just use the MFC wrappers. So there might be a workaround possible in the VCL sources.

Comment: @Lenonardo: Thanks for your time. I have six pairs of key_value to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to say "It works for me, on windows 7, 64 bit, with delphi XE." In fact, it did work, the first time I dropped it onto the form, it all worked great. And I thought, you're doing something wrong.  Then it hit me, after the second time, I reopened the form.

Now it always fails.

I think you should start with a new blank project like I did, and do just the one thing.  That takes all the other things you did out of the code, that are messing you up.

I call this the "file new" test. If you can't reproduce something in a new application, that contains only the code or controls you are unsure about, don't bother asking anybody else to do it for you.

[image]

Here is my initial try, it worked:

Second time I reopened the form, it failed at designtime, the same way it failed for David H.

Dump the widths of the panels to a memo like this:

```
procedure TForm3.DumpWidths;
var
 t:Integer;
begin
 for t := 0 to StatusBar1.Panels.Count-1 do begin
   Memo1.Lines.Add( '#'+IntToStr(t)+
   ' width '+
   IntToStr(StatusBar1.Panels.Items[t].Width));
 end;

end;
```

The VCL Status Bar wraps an MS Common control, which either has a bug, or the VCL is wrapping it wrong. Since this doesn't happen on XP, I think you've found a new MS Common Controls bug in Win7.

Comment: @Warren: I do use a new empty project :)

Comment: @Warren: `If you can't reproduce something in a new application, that contains only the code or controls you are unsure about, don't bother asking anybody else to do it for you.` I always bear it in mind.

Comment: @Warren: You mean in your machine the text is only shown in run time? It is strange but in my machine the text is indeed only shown in design time. :D

Comment: This also reproduces in Win7/64bit, on Delphi 7 VCL. I seriously doubt this is a VCL bug.  It has to be a regression in the MS Common controls library.    With crap like that floating around in the library, I would rip this out, and use a non-COMMON-controls status bar.

Comment: @Warren: Thank you very much for your suggestion! Could you help to recommend one `non-COMMON-controls status bar`?

Comment: I use Toolbar2000+spTBX, others use Developer Express, or TMS.

Comment: For your case (12+ pieces of text) I would just use TPaintBox. :-)

Comment: @Warren: Thank you very much for sharing your experience! Also, thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't show beyond the 10th in design-time:

[image]

But at run-time is looks like this:

[image]

All properties set in the .dfm file.

As to why it is like this I've no idea. But since it behaves fine at run-time I don't think will cause any serious problems.

---

As requested by Warren, here's my .dfm:

```
object Form3: TForm3
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form3'
  ClientHeight = 105
  ClientWidth = 635
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'MS Sans Serif'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object StatusBar1: TStatusBar
    Left = 0
    Top = 86
    Width = 635
    Height = 19
    Panels = <
      item
        Text = '1'
        Width = 50
      end
      item
        Text = '2'
        Width = 50
      end
      item
        Text = '3'
        Width = 50
      end
      item
        Text = '4'
        Width = 50
      end
      item
        Text = '5'
        Width = 50
      end
      item
        Text = '6'
        Width = 50
      end
      item
        Text = '7'
        Width = 50
      end
      item
        Text = '8'
        Width = 50
      end
      item
        Text = '9'
        Width = 50
      end
      item
        Text = '10'
        Width = 50
      end
      item
        Text = '11'
        Width = 50
      end
      item
        Text = '12'
        Width = 50
      end
      item
        Text = '13'
        Width = 50
      end>
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you dump your DFM as text and append?

Comment: @David:Thanks very much for your time! Oh my god, the behavior is reversed in your machine! In my machine, the text is not shown in run time instead. :D

Comment: I think with three of us reproducing it, the sensible answer is, this is a bug in MS Common Controls library.  I wonder why it starts screwing up, only after my second try

Comment: @David: Not a problem on your system. However, Xichen sees same behaviour at runtime.  Gives me a bad feeling.

Comment: @Warren It never occurred to me that the behaviour might be different on different systems. Weird!

Comment: What is even more weird is this: MS Visual Studio 2008 winforms applications do NOT LET YOU ADD more than 10 panels to a status bar.  Perhaps they got a memo that we didn't get? Oh wait. They do let you. You just have to change the text to make it smaller.

Comment: @David, @Warrent: After I save the project, and reopen it, the text after the 10th panels is gone both in design time and run time. (I have edited my question to reflect this)

Comment: This is trouble in 64 bit OS. It is broken on WinXP x64 and on Win7 x64. Compiled with Delphi 2006 and 2010.

Comment: No, sorry :( Even custom paint is broken.

Comment: Reproduced here, Win 7 64 bit, does not show in designer, but shows ok in runtime. Flipping the BiDiMode value has the effect of (temporarily) correcting the display in the designer, may be worth trying this at runtime? Cannot test here as it works ok at runtime.

Comment: I remember MS Common Controls version changes between Win 95, 98, and 2000 caused me merry hell for many years. Since the XP release, things in MS Common Controls, have been stable, until I see this.

Comment: @DiGi: Thanks for your time!  @HMcG: Thank you very much for your suggestion! @Warren: Thank you very much for sharing your experience!

Answer (score 2):

I found a similar problem for ownerdraw panels. DrawPanel event is not called on panels with an index > 6 in Win 7/64bit. I found that windows does not send WM_DRAWITEM message to these panels. Solution that worked in my case is to set the WS_EX_COMPOSITED style to statusbar.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  SBHandle: THandle;
begin
  ...
  if CheckWin32Version(5, 1) then
  begin
    SBHandle:= StatusBar.Handle;
    SetWindowLong(SBHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(SBHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE) or WS_EX_COMPOSITED);
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Very good information.   Anybody else reading who knows of any bugs in other MS Common Controls?